# Recommendation for a tax calculation and filing system?

Tags: database, erp, integrations

Right now my company uses Avalara to perform the functions of tax calculation, tax filing, tax exempt certificate management, and address validation. However, we want to end our contract with Avalara and switch to a different tax calculation system. Our reasons for wanting to switch away from Avalara are because they have extremely slow to respond in many standard customer service interactions (despite our recent upgrade to enterprise-level support), they treated us very poorly during our last contract renewal negotiation, and we feel that we may be overpaying for the services we are receiving from them.

What tax systems would you recommend we look into? We are a not-for-profit business that is 100% ecommerce based. We have multiple ship-from locations, we have nexuses in multiple states, we work with taxable and tax-exempt customers, and we do business in all 50 states and Canada.

Any recommendations for a new tax system would be appreciated. We would need the system to handle tax calculation, tax filing, tax exempt certificate management, and address validation. Thanks.

Comment: Dive into these comparisons: - https://www.g2.com/products/avalara/competitors/alternatives - https://www.trustradius.com/products/avalara/competitors - https://www.gartner.com/reviews/market/tax-software/vendor/avalara/product/avalara-platform/alternatives - https://www.capterra.com/p/75673/AvaTax/alternatives/ - https://www.getapp.com/finance-accounting-software/a/avatax/alternatives/ And find a good number of candidates. Ask if the re are discounts for non-for-profit. Schedule demo with the Sales department of the software's you like.